# eclipse exiting with java was started but returned exit code

Tags: android, eclipse

Java was started but returned edit code = 1 error while starting the app.
here is my error report
[image]

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem some days ago. Reinstall the latest version of Eclipse ADT fixed my problem.
Hope it helps
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of Eclipse and java is `64-bit`. If so, then point to the location of `jvm.dll` file inside your `eclipse.ini` file using `-vm` argument. 
The `-vm` option must be placed after the other Eclipse-specific options (such as -product, --launcher.*, etc), but before the -vmargs option. For more details refer [eclipse wiki page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\IBM\Java71\jre\bin\j9vm.jvm.dll
```