# java was started but returned exit code

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, exit-code

when i was starting eclipse, i first got this error dialog:
[image]

After this error,i researched and found a solution [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example).

this solution asked me to give this line in eclipse.ini:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
```

but after adding this, i found another kind of error dialog:

[image]

after this error,i researched alot, 
and found these **solutions** [sol1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166007/when-starting-up-eclipse-c-c-it-doesnt-open-but-gives-a-error-java-was-start) ,[sol2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027485/eclipse-exiting-with-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code)
after following these, error is not resolved. does anyone know why i am facing this problem.

**note: i know this is kind of duplicate question, but all those duplicate question are not resolved yet, so do not mark this as duplicate!**

Comment: considering your reputation, you must have already done it :P, but then again.. did u check your path variable???... have you installed JDK and JRE and set the paths for then??

Comment: i would rather uninstalling java, removing anything reletaed to java in system variables/paths, then install a new JDK. i would download a new eclipse, besause there is(maybe) corrupted settings in the old allready installed eclipse package

Comment: @Rami.Q - Ya.. I had to do the same when I had this issue..

Comment: What about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635506/error-starting-eclipse-in-linux-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13 ?

Comment: Check your PATH environmental variable and make sure you have an up-to-date JDK. Possibly redownload your JDK. Also make sure your Eclipse and JDK are the same bit version (32 bit and 32 bit or 64 bit and 64 bit).

Comment: i have mentioned research in my question,the problem is i don't want to reinstall

Comment: i want to resolve it without unstall and install again,becuase it is not the solution,it is like jugad,and i want the solution!

Comment: also i have checked the enviroment variable and all the required stuff

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to run a 64-bit Eclipse with a 32-bit Java Runtime.  They have to match.

Comment: Amazing! it really solved my problem, and it is common we never try to understand these errors shown in dialogs, and we hit our head with walls and pull our hairs that why this error is coming before reading the error properly :)

Comment: @nitind, what do you mean by 64-bit Eclipse? if we want to download Eclipse we have two choices windows 32 and 64, For me i have a windows 64 but i need to run JVM 32-bit because i must install Jboss tools, what should i do ?

Comment: The JVM and Eclipse *must* match because the JVM has to load native DLLs for the UI controls, and on Windows you can't mix 32-bit and 64-bit code in the same process. If you require a 32-bit JVM, you must use a 32-bit download of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently updated your java then please uninstall that update.
It worked in my case. Hope it will help.

Answer (score -1):

first of all remove line in eclipse.ini:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
```

then

right click::my computer

select: properties

click on : advanced system setting

click on: environments variable

select: path

click: edit

copy on : your java(jdk) path eg.[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin]

paste on edit user variable dialog box: eg. [;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin.;]

ok/apply

then start ur eclipse and enjoy..........