# Error with setting up Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

The image basically shows it all, it's saying that I don't have the JRE or JDK in the file path, buuuut, thing is, there isn't even a jre fie in there. I have just downloaded and extracted the ADT Bundle from the the android site so everything should be there?

[image]

After downloading JDK, I, went to where it downloaded, in the C: drive, and copied the jre7 file to my eclipse file, I then renamed the jre7 to jre.... this presents me with this error, please make sure there are no hard objects around as you may injure yourself if you throw a rage at my stupidity, keep in mind that I am completely new to this stuff, the only partially advanced knowledge I have about computers is a very shallow knowledge of Python.

http://oi42.tinypic.com/mhsuxg.jpg

RESOLVED, after getting the jre I realized that I had a 32-bit pack, so I downloaded the 64-bit and now it works.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have Java installed at all. Download yourself a JDK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java was started but returned exit code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604471/java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code)

Answer (score 1):

No,actually The ADT bundle only provides **The Android SDK** with **`Eclipse`** and does not give JRE or JDK,you need to manually install JDK from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) or some other site and have to add the Installation directory to your `%PATH%` environmental variable
For more info [go here](http://www.xda-developers.com/xda-tv-2/how-to-build-an-android-app-part-1-setting-up-eclipse-and-android-sdk-xda-tv/)

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [Java JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) Seems like you don't have JDK installed

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Java JDK and Java virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

error shows that you haven't installed jdk! 
Download and install [Java JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

if error comes again,then see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604471/java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code).